# How to redirect pages in old website to same path in multiple websites randomly

Tags: javascript

I have a code to redirect page in old website to same path in new website
but I need to redirect page to same path for multiple websites randomly
website1.com , website2.com and website3.com

```
window.location.href = "http://" + "website1.com/" + window.location.pathname
```

Comment: Javascript is not the best tool for this. Look into doing redirections on the server side using whatever your stack allows, eg. .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, if you insist on doing on the client

```js
const sites = ["site1.com","site2.com","site3.com"];
let site = sites[Math.floor(Math.random()*sites.length)];
let url = `https://${site}${window.location.pathname}`;
console.log(url)
//window.location.href = url;
```